# improve doc-view display quality

Tags: pdf, docview

The fonts in my pdf's as displayed in doc-view aren't particularly readable. Is there a setting I can change to improve the image quality? I tried changing `doc-view-resolution` from 100 to 300, but that just made the pdf render larger.

Comment: `(doc-view-clear-cache)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by "render larger" you mean that the dimensions of the rendered png image are larger, then you could use some of the `doc-view` functions to fit the image to your window: `doc-view-fit-page-to-window`, `doc-view-fit-width-to-window`, and `doc-view-fit-height-to-window`.

In other words, increase the resolution of the rendered image as you did, and then fit (probably shrink) the sharper image with the `...-fit-...` functions.

Comment: sadly, these commands don't appreciably improve the rendering quality. This is especially noticeable for figures.

Comment: It turns out that doc-view was rendering the PDF fine. The PDF output from LaTeX was just really low quality.

Comment: @wdkrnls so how did you improve on it? Asking because it seems I have the same problem

Comment: For the resolution change to take effect one first has to kill all buffers displaying the pdf and run `doc-view-clear-cache`.

Comment: Note that solution with 'doc-view-resolution' works only when doc-view-scale-internally is on and imagemagic support is enabled. Otherwise Emacs does rescaling by changing doc-view-resolution to a lower value.